# "Heap size" is growing way faster than "Used heap"

Tags: java, garbage-collection, heap-memory, visualvm

the `Heap size` of my java application is continuously growing till it reaches the `Max Heap size`of `1G`. Why is that so?

I start my application with those parameters:

```
java -Xmx1G -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseShenandoahGC -XX:ShenandoahUncommitDelay=5000 -XX:ShenandoahGuaranteedGCInterval=10000 -Dlog4j.configurationFile=./log4j2.xml -jar applicaiton.jar
```

[image: Difference of Heap size and Used heap is grwoing]

Edit:
When I restart my application you see there isn't a gap between "Heap size" and "Used Heap" but this gap is getting bigger and bigger, can I somehow limit that gap?

[image]

Comment: may be because this is how your app allocates objects?

Comment: Use VisualVM and check why heap size is growing. Provide more details also.

Comment: @Eugene in my understanding the blue line("Used Heap") is what my application actually needs?

Comment: @user2071938 yes the blue line is what you "actually" need, but yellow is what you "have commited to" at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

I am not particularly familiar with the way that the new Shenandoah GC normally behaves.  However, there is nothing particularly alarming (to me) with that graph.

According to https://shipilev.net/talks/devoxx-Nov2017-shenandoah.pdf, the *modus operandi* (MO) of a this GC with regards to memory utilization is a bit different to some other collectors.

> "We shall take all the memory when we need it, but we shall also give it back when we don’t".

If there is significant load on the allocator (i.e. lots of objects being allocated) Shenandoah will aggressively expand the heap.  This is based on the observation that a low-pause GC is most efficient (and most likely to keep up!) if it has plenty of space to work in.

But the flipside is that if your system is idle, the GC will give memory back to the OS more freely than many other GCs.

---

This seems to fit the memory graph in your question.

The other thing to note is that the heap size (orange) is nowhere near your max-heap limit.  If you get close to that limit, the GC will stop growing the heap.

Finally, note that you can apparently encourage Shenandoah to give back uncommitted memory faster by using a smaller value for the `-XX:ShenandoahUncommitDelay=<millis>` option.  However, it is recommended to NOT make it too small because that is liable to slow down the allocator.

(Source: https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2017/11/minimize-java-memory-usage-right-garbage-collector.html)

Comment: hi! There is no significant load, even so the Heap size is increasing till it reaches the Max Heap size. I have running a few java processes, any process can hav a max size of 1G but if every process allocates 1G there is not enough space on my OS. The max heap size is just to manage spikes. So I need the GC to release space when they are not needed anymore!

Comment: There must be sufficient load to make the JVM think that the allocator is not idle for (erm) 5,000 milliseconds.   If you want the GC to give memory back more often, try decreasing the `-XX:ShenandoahUncommitDelay` value.

Comment: I was going to have a look at the source code to see if there were other relevant tuning options.  The repo site is borked at the moment.

Comment: thx! I edited my answer to show how the GC performs when I restart my application

Comment: this does not answer the question as it is. the OP showed the visualVM in minutes and `ShenandoahUncommitDelay` setting is only `5000` ms; the un-commit should have happened, making `ShenandoahUncommitDelay` even smaller will make no difference

Comment: and btw `ShenandoahUncommitDelay` does not have to do much (or directly) with the allocator, it's _when_ to un-commit certain regions that stayed *empty* for the at least this period.